# Ionic SqlStorage is not defined

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to use SqlStorage in an ionic app. I'm getting the error in the title. I'm guessing I need to include SqlStorage but I'm not sure where. My code looks a lot like what's in the docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/SqlStorage/ . How do you include SqlStorage?

```html
var prefrences = {
foo: bar
}
let storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
storage.set('storedPreferences', preferences);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add SqlStorage to your list of 'include' packages via import statement. i.e

```
import {SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';
```

For example

```
    import {SqlStorage,...} from 'ionic-angular';

    @Page({
      templateUrl: 'path/to/template'
    })

    export class MyPage {
       constructor(){
          let storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
          ...
       }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: where is that located? I saw an example that looked like that but no part of the app I started with looks like that. my app.js looks like `angular.module('app', ['ionic','ngCordova', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives',])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {...`

Comment: It sounds like you are using Ionic v1. The docs you are looking at are for Ionic v2. Integrated SqlStorage is a v2 feature

Comment: That was the issue, I was using v1